# How to create dropdown menu with nested submenu using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

i want to create a dropdown menu with nested submenu so that when users over on a submenu it should display its dropdown list and when the mouse is taken out of the submenu it should hide its dropdown list. i have tried but it works only with on click() method but i want to use on hover(). here is my code
html

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="banner">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="design/img/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
                    <h6><small>Some text</small></h6>
                </div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="main-navigation">
                        <li class=""><a href="#">Accueil</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Groupe Cible <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                 <li class="dropdown-submenu" id="men">
                  <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">Cible Etudes & Conseils <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu" id="men">
                      <a class="test" tabindex="-1">Qui Sommes Nous <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                   <li class="dropdown-submenu" id="men">
                    <a class="test" href="#" tabindex="0" data-toggle="dropdown">Présentation </a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#"tabindex="0">Cible Etudes/Conseil</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" tabindex="0">Notre Vision</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" tabindex="0">Notre Mission</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" tabindex="0">Nos Valeurs</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" tabindex="0">Notre Force</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" tabindex="0">Nos Filiales</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#" tabindex="0">Notre Equipe</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" tabindex="0">Nous Ecrire</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" tabindex="0">Retrouvez Nous </a></li>
                </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu" id="men">
                <a class="test" tabindex="0" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Notre Offre  </a>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                   <li class="dropdown-submenu" id="men">
                    <a class="test" tabindex="0" data-toggle="dropdown">Les Enquêtes et Sondage</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a tabindex="0">procédures Qualité</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" tabindex="0">Méthodes</a></li>
                      <li><a tabindex="0">outils de Collecte</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown-submenu" id="men">
                    <a class="test" tabindex="0" data-toggle="dropdown">Les Etudes</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li class="test" class="dropdown-submenu">
                        <a class="test" href="#" tabindex="0" data-toggle="dropdown">Marketing</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a tabindex="0">Marché</a></li>
                          <li><a tabindex="0">Consommateurs</a></li>
                          <li><a tabindex="0">Stratégie Marketing</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                        <a class="test" class="test" href="<?=url::site('fr/a_propos/14/development')?>" tabindex="0" data-toggle="dropdown">Développement</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a tabindex="0">Impact environnemental</a></li>
                          <li><a tabindex="0">Développement Urbain et Local</a></li>
                          <li><a tabindex="0">Assainissement</a></li>
                          <li><a tabindex="0">Evaluation des projets et programmes</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li><a tabindex="0">Moyens Logistiques</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                   <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                    <a class="test" tabindex="0" data-toggle="dropdown">Le Conseil</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a tabindex="0">Conseil en Marketing</a></li>
                      <li><a tabindex="0">Conseil en Gestion</a></li>
                      <li><a tabindex="0">Recherche de Financement</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                    <a class="test" tabindex="0" data-toggle="dropdown">La Formation </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a tabindex="0">Formation en Vente</a></li>
                      <li><a tabindex="0">Formation en Marketing</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                    <a class="test" href="#" tabindex="0" data-toggle="dropdown">Nous Ont Fait Confiance  </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" >
                      <li><a href="#" tabindex="0">Cameroun</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" tabindex="0">Afrique</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" tabindex="0">L'international</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a class="test" href="#" tabindex="0" data-toggle="dropdown">Où Intervenons Nous </a>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#" tabindex="0">Cameroun</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" tabindex="0">Gabon</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" tabindex="0">Tchad</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" tabindex="0">Congo Brazzaville</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" tabindex="0">Côte d’Ivoire</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" tabindex="0">Burkina Faso</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" tabindex="0">Mauritanie</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" tabindex="0">Mali</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" tabindex="0">Bénin</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" tabindex="0">Guinée Conakry</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" tabindex="0">Niger</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" tabindex="0">Togo</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" tabindex="0">Djibouti</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" tabindex="0">Rwanda</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" tabindex="0">Burundi</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a class="test" href="#" tabindex="0" data-toggle="dropdown">Nos Publications  </a>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#" tabindex="0" href="">Articles</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" tabindex="0" href="">Résultats</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" tabindex="0" href="">New</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
<!-- =========================== cible RH ============================== -->
                  <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a class="test" href="#" tabindex="0" data-toggle="dropdown">Cible RH Emploi</a>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a class="test" href="#" tabindex="0" data-toggle="dropdown">Qui Sommes Nous </a>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                   <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                    <a class="test" href="#" tabindex="0" data-toggle="dropdown">Présentation </a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a tabindex="0">Cible RH Emploi</a></li>
                      <li><a tabindex="0">Notre Vision</a></li>
                      <li><a tabindex="0">Notre Mission</a></li>
                      <li><a tabindex="0">Nos Valeurs</a></li>
                      <li><a tabindex="0">Notre Force</a></li>
                      <li><a tabindex="0">Nos Filiales</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#" tabindex="0">Notre Equipe</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" tabindex="0">Nous Ecrire</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" tabindex="0">Retrouvez Nous </a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li ><a  href="#">Notre Offre  </a> </li>
              <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                    <a class="test" href="#" tabindex="0" data-toggle="dropdown">Nous Ont Fait Confiance  </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#" tabindex="0">Cameroun</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" tabindex="0">Afique</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" tabindex="0">L'international</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
              <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a class="test" href="#" tabindex="0" data-toggle="dropdown">Où Intervenons Nous </a>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#" tabindex="0">Cameroun</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" tabindex="0">Gabon</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" tabindex="0">Tchad</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" tabindex="0">Congo Brazzaville</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" tabindex="0">Côte d’Ivoire</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" tabindex="0">Burkina Faso</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" tabindex="0">Mauritanie</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" tabindex="0">Mali</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" tabindex="0">Bénin</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" tabindex="0">Guinée Conakry</a></li>
                  <li><a href="" tabindex="0">Niger</a></li>
                  <li><a href="" tabindex="0">Togo</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" tabindex="0">Djibouti</a></li>
                  <li><a href="" tabindex="0">Rwanda</a></li>
                  <li><a href="" tabindex="0">Burundi</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown-submenu" id="men">
                <a class="test" href="" tabindex="0" data-toggle="dropdown">Nos Publications  </a>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="" tabindex="0" href="">Articles</a></li>
                  <li><a href="" tabindex="0" href="">Résultats</a></li>
                  <li><a href="" tabindex="0" href="">New</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </li>
                        <li class="dropdown <?=(!empty($service))?"active":""?>">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Services <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li>Web Design</li>
                                <li>SEO</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li class="dropdown <?=(!empty($client))?"active":""?>">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Clients <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                               <li>MTN</li>
                               <li>Apple</li> 
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li class="dropdown <?=(!empty($equipe))?"active":""?>">
                          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Team <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>Mark</li>
                            <li>John</li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li class="dropdown <?=(!empty($partenaire))?"active":""?>">
                          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Partners <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>Bootstrap</li>
                            <li>Ubuntu</li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li class="dropdown <?=(!empty($actualite))?"active":""?>">
                          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">News <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                           <li>Perl</li>
                           <li>Python</li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li class="dropdown <?=(!empty($project))?"active":""?>">
                          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Projects <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>Java</li>
                            <li>Ajax</li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li class="dropdown <?=(!empty($contact))?"active":""?>">
                          <a  href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Contacts <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Contact Cible Etudes/Conseils</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Contact Cible RH</a></li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>

                    </ul>


          </div>
          </div>
          </nav>
```

then my jquery

```
    $('a.test + ul').css("display","none");
$('.dropdown-submenu').css("position","relative");
$('.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu').css({"top": "0","left": "100%","margin-top": "-1px"});
$('ul.dropdown-menu [data-toggle=dropdown]').on('click', function(event) {
    // Avoid following the href location when clicking
    event.preventDefault(); 
    // Avoid having the menu to close when clicking
    event.stopPropagation(); 
    // Re-add .open to parent sub-menu item
    $(this).parent().addClass('open');
    $(this).parent().find("ul").parent().find("li.dropdown").addClass('open');
});
```

please help me! Thanks.

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to write the **new JQuery code** yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by simply using CSS like follows-

```
.dropdown-submenu:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0; // remove the gap so it doesn't close
}
```

[Working fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/schikara/t0ctmxoj/2/)

Comment: Nice horizontal dropdown. How would you make it vertical?